# Thonny cant recognize raspberry pico WH?

Tags: python, python-3.x, upload, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

I have just started using a pico WH and i wwanted to upload a file to it but the "option upload to..."
isnt there.The Pico is shown like a normal drive and not like this:
https://docs.sunfounder.com/projects/kepler-kit/en/latest/_images/th_done1.png
im using this tutorial:
https://docs.sunfounder.com/projects/kepler-kit/en/latest/pyproject/python_start/upload_libraries.html

I have tried reopening the thonny and and plugging the pico in and out while pressing the bootsel button down but still nothing!I have updated the firmware to the newest version.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Thonny couldn't find the Raspberry Pi Pico WH automatically. The solution was to manually select it.